# What is wrong with this sql statement, produces a mysqli error near series_seasons = '12'

Tags: php, mysql

I have a page that updates a record for a TV series, however the SQL statement does not seem to work, I have looked at it for a few hours and I think I have gone 'code blind' can any body assist? all the variable seem to be fine, but I am getting "please check your MySQL code near SET series_seasons = '12' "

```
$ussql="UPDATE epg_series SET `series_name`='Red Dwarf', SET `series_seasons`='12', SET `series_year_start`='', SET `series_year_end`='-', SET `series_seasondata`='', SET `series_IMDB`='tt0094535', SET `series_regular_cast`='' WHERE `series_abbr` = 'RDDWARF'";



$result= mysqli_query($conn,$ussql) or die("ERROR: Could not insert record.<hr>".mysqli_query($conn)."<hr>".$uspsql."<hr>");
```

I am expecting to update the database but it fails, I have even tried in Navicat and Navicat reports

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'SET `series_seasons`='12', SET `series_year_start`='', SET
>   `series_year_end`='-'' at line 1

Comment: MYSQL v5.7.24 PHP v7.2.14 running on WAMP v3.1.7

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Why do you keep repeating `SET`?  Have you tried progressively simplifying the query such as by removing the `SET series_seasons='12',` to see if that fixes or changes things? An [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Too many SET  ..  try

```
$ussql="UPDATE epg_series 
    SET `series_name`='Red Dwarf', 
     `series_seasons`='12', 
     `series_year_start`='', 
     `series_year_end`='-', 
     `series_seasondata`='', 
     `series_IMDB`='tt0094535', 
     `series_regular_cast`='' 
    WHERE `series_abbr` = 'RDDWARF'";
```

Comment: Thankyou for the straight forward answer, I knew it was something simple but was nagging me for ages, Thanks again scaisEdge

Answer (score 3):

Your MySQL syntax is incorrect; `UPDATE` only expects a single `SET` declaration, followed by a comma-separated list of columns to update and their associated values. From the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html):

```
UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_reference
    SET assignment_list
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [ORDER BY ...]
    [LIMIT row_count]

value:
    {expr | DEFAULT}

assignment:
    col_name = value

assignment_list:
    assignment [, assignment] ...
```

The linked documentation page goes on to show this example for multiple fields being set in a single query:

```
UPDATE t1 SET col1 = col1 + 1, col2 = col1;
```